# Switching App_Theme / MasterPages: Could not load file or assembly App_Web_include.ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET project with has multiple App_Themes, which are usually static-per-site (every customer has their own theme), but which can be switched on the fly (some customers have more than one theme). For example, if someone logs in as a staff member, in some instances they get a different theme to what the public see.

When I compile a new version and then switch theme, I get an error like this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_include.ascx.6bb32623.ifp8_yu6,    Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It goes away if I force a recompilation by touching web.config, but it's annoying me, I'd like to understand the underlying mechanism, and where I have a production site that uses multiple theme, it's too easy to install an upgrade, test the default one (which works) and then forget to check the other (which don't until poked).

The different themes also use different MasterPages. Both the Theme and the MasterPage files are set in the PreInit of the page base depending on the selected skin.

The problem didn't occur when I was originally building the theme/masterpage switching system - it's come along with an upgrade to a new version of Visual Studio or .NET runtime at some point in the last year or two.

Any clues?